# ASP.NET DES encryption with encrypted text length equal to plain text length

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, cryptography, des

I am looking to encrypt a string of text using DES algorithm but the requirement is that the encrypted string length should be the same as the plain text string length. I have already tried to use the option CipherMode.CTS, but getting the CryptoGraphicException "Specified Cipher mode is not valid for this algorithm."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show us the code you've tried.

Comment: DES is not secure at all, and ECB mode (and CTS) is not either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3435/Secure-Architecture-Design-Methodologies) from some time ago.

> The CTS mode is not supported by any of the symmetric encryption algorithms currently shipped with the .NET Framework BCL. It is included to support new symmetric algorithms that might derive from the SymmetricAlgorithm class at a later time.

This article is from 2002, but after doing further investigation, the quote above seems to still be accurate.

Fortunately for you though, [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) does support CTS.

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new CtsBlockCipher(new CbcBlockCipher(new AesEngine()));
    ICipherParameters keyParam = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), iv);
    cipher.Init(true, keyParam);
    return cipher.DoFinal(data, 0, data.Length);
}

public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new CtsBlockCipher(new CbcBlockCipher(new AesEngine()));
    ICipherParameters keyParam = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), iv);
    cipher.Init(false, keyParam);
    return cipher.DoFinal(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

CBC is used in this example and you'll need to use a fixed IV since you likely don't have anywhere to store a random IV for each encryption (which would be preferable). If there is any way you can change the encrypted data length requirement, you should probably do so and use AES with CBC and a random IV instead. **At the very minimum** though, use AES instead of DES (as in the code above). DES is insecure regardless of whatever block cipher mode you use with it.

There are two further things you should keep in mind.

First, CTS (in the Bouncy Castle implementation) requires that the data you're encrypting be at least one block in length. So if you use AES, your data will need to be at least 16 bytes, or if you use DES it'll need to be at least 8 bytes.

Second, if you're encrypting text you need to keep in mind that your encrypted data will be binary, and you may not be able to store it in the same location as your unencrypted text without encoding it to Hex or Base64 first (which will increase it's length).

**Update**

A side note on the strength/security of CTS: Given ntoskrnl's comment about ECB with CTS (which is correct), I thought it prudent to investigate if CTS weakens CBC in any way. But it appears [that it does not](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9877/strength-of-cbc-with-ciphertext-stealing/9879?noredirect=1#9879).